# Unpacking rar file with unrar said 'No files to extract' but in windows unpacked perfectly the same archive

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate

I have one issue with unrar command. When I'm going to unpack some archives using unrar command I get the message 'No files to extract'. If I extract the same file in a Windows system with winrar the files are extracted perfectly. The rar file was compressed in 2008 using winrar, but I don't know which version was used to do it.

However, others rar files are uncompressed without any problem.

My unrar version is 5.30 and my system is Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Is there anyone with the same issue?

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks